# HQL select sum and time group by time unit (hour/day/month) and

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I have a table like this:

```
COLUMN               TYPE
------------------------------
ID                   INTEGER
VALUE                INTEGER
TIME                 TIMESTAMP
```

How can I write query with HQL selecting sum of value column groupped by time unit(f.e. groupped by day) and selecting this time unit as a second column.

I have tried to do it and got something like this:
but there is no parsedatetime function in HQL so I have no idea how can I get the proper query now.

```
select sum(value),
parsedatetime(day(time) || '.' || month(time) || '.' || year(time) || ' ' || hour(time) ||':00:00', 'dd.MM.yy hh:mm:ss')
as xtime 
from Table 
group by time
```

I want this query to return object with 2 fields: int and java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are grouping by whole the datetime value, that's why you haven't expected result, you must group it by the piece of datetime that you want, try something like below:

```
select sum(value),
day(time) as xtime 
from Table 
group by day(time)
```

Comment: but I want this query to return object with two fields: int and java.sql.Date

Comment: Ok, so if multiple datetime values had same day then which of them you want to bring as second column?

Comment: this is the reason I've tried to do it like via parsedatetime func. maybe I should group by day(time)||month(time) so I won't have this problem, because quering data for several years if out of scope for me

Comment: yes, then you will have to group it by day(time)||month(time)