# HQL: group by hour(time) and sum(pcount)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I am using this query to give me sum count which is grouped by hour

```
@Query(value = "select sum(PC.count) as pcounts, hour(PC.time) as hourly from ProductCount as PC where PC.time >= :currentDate and PC.time < :nextDate group by hour(PC.time)")
List<Map> findByCountAndGroupByTime(@Param("currentDate") Timestamp currentDate, @Param("nextDate") Timestamp nextDate);
```

However, the result I get for date is `Integer`. Yeah, in the docs it says that hour(time) will give an integer.

If I want it to be in `Date` or `Timestamp`, what do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the `HOUR()` function extract the hour part from the passed date (so the Integer result), if you need a date set as PC.time truncated to the extracted hour, simply get also the other needed parts (`DAY(PC.time), MONTH(PC.time), YEAR(PC.time)`) and build a new calendar with these values.

Comment: Do you mean something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710305/hql-select-sum-and-time-group-by-time-unit-hour-day-month-and
Or I do that in Java using Calendar?

Comment: If you need to group only by hour you should keep your query as is. Simply extract also the other parts of the timestamp you need and manually build your hour truncated timestamp with Calendar or Joda DateTime or what you want.